# Setting mut on a computed property

Tags: ember.js

I have a parent component that needs to do validation of child components:

```
// parent component.js

isValid: computed.and('child1Valid','child2Valid', ...),
child1Valid: null,
child2Valid: null,
...

// parent template

{{ child1 
    prop1=true 
    prop2=false 
    childIsValidated: (mut child1Valid) 
}}
```

So the parent can mutate its `childIsValidated` property and the change should propagate to its parent's `child1Valid` property.

```
// child1 component.js

prop1: null,
prop2: null,
childIsValidated: computed.or('prop1','prop2')
```

As I understand it, the parent is passing down (and overriding) `childIsValidated` unintentionally. Can I somehow say that `childIsValidated` is both computed and a sort of alias for the parent's `child1Valid` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible, because an object key can't be two different functions (computed.or vs computed.alias) at the same time.

Also, Ember intentionally overwrites properties when passed through the templates (If it didn't both your prop1 & prop2 would still be null in the child component)

Some alternate solutions include putting an observer on prop1 & prop2 and setting child1Validated when they change.

Or you might be able to pass an action back up to the component when each prop changes

Comment: Right now my solution is to pass an the handler down the line from the parent:
`{{child1 .. onValidChange=(action (mut childIsValidated)) }}` and to update from a child action. Seems like one of the approaches you described

Comment: That is the approach that I would have taken, and is consistent with Ember's data down, actions up paradigm